# Access Denied Error while integrating odoo13 with keycloak

Tags: odoo, keycloak, odoo-13

I have tried integrating odoo13 with keycloak following the steps given in the website:

https://janikvonrotz.ch/2020/04/24/odoo-oauth-authentication-with-keycloak/

After following the steps, I'm getting keycloak login page when **Sign in** is clicked in odoo page, validation is also done well but it is redirected to odoo login page with **Access Denied** Error.

I understand that keycloak creates session upon login, but odoo is unable to get any information after login.

Can anyone help to find where the error is and resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance!!